# При выборе Prefab-а crash Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Открываю Юнити нажимаю на Prefab и Юнити выключается, никакой ошибки не выдаёт, а просто закрывает юнити и всё. Может кто знает почему?

Comment: Ну так удали этот префаб

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, напишите в поддержку Unity3d или переустановите редактор. Попробуйте нажать на другой prefab

Comment: Нажимал на другой преф всё работает, но ведь они мне нужны все префабы, удалил префабы и салил заново вот это и помогло